# Need to know what type of bike frame this is

Tags: identify-this-bike, downhill

[image]

Bought this frame a couple years ago as project to build. Want to start getting it built but can't find any of the info I got with frame when I purchased it.

Comment: Well, it's a Scott of some kind. Did you not mention that because you thought it was too obvious or because you've not actually looked at their website?

Comment: Did have a look at the website but wasn't sure if it was a Scott Voltage or a Gambler. Bought the frame a couple years ago 2nd hand for £600 but has been sitting in loft until today. Want to start to build it now.So once I can get it identified which model it is then I can start ordering the parts. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't look like either of those models, based on web searching.  Those two seat-post "stays"  that go either side of the main suspension are quite unusual.  The chain tensioner on the bottom bracket is also uncommon.  To my eye, the bottom bracket hole looks awfully small diameter.  The rear triangle looks "adjustable" - perhaps it can take a 26" or a 27.5" wheel ?   I think your best plan is to search hard and find the paperwork from when you bought the frame.

Comment: Also consider, you're building a bike the most expensive way.  All the parts separately will cost more than a new bike assembled and warrantied.  So you might want to look out for some part-donor bikes.  You need a lot of parts to make this into a bike.

Comment: Try a rear wheel in it and some salvaged brake arms to see what wheel diameter it seems most suited to.  That will at least separate the 26" bikes from the 700c/29" ones.

Comment: The chain tensioner points towards a downhill type bike.

Comment: I've just emailed Scott USA to see if they can tell me which model it is. Hopefully I'll find out soon but thanks everyone.

Comment: Scott  Octane, circa late 1990's or early 2000's should get you started. Looking at the rear triangle, a wild guess is its a very early model, possibly prototype. good luck - worth the effort to build up for prosperity, parts will be very hard to come by.

Comment: Really nice socks. I appreciate a good socks shot.

Answer (score 3):

I've emailed Scott USA and here's the answer:

> We have searched high and low. 
>   No one can find any info on this bike
>   at all! It’s that old. Sorry we couldn’t help..

My own search did not bring up anything useful either. I think this is either some other bike with Scott decals or an one-off prototype, given frame finish and configurable linkage.

**Update:** This is Scott FX DH 1996. [Confirmation link](https://www.pinkbike.com/photo/5270752/).

[image]

Comment: +1 for providing closure.  Remember to accept this answer using the tick/checkbox on the left, below the score.

Comment: In light of this, you have two main possibilities.  Build the bike with suitable parts that fit and simply ride it.  Or if building it will be too expensive, sell it off now as-is for what you can get.  Its rarity might help you afford a complete and more -standard bike.   Older MTB stuff is going to be harder to find in good nick, and won't leave you with a "modern" bike.  You could even ask Scott if they want to buy it for their museum.

Comment: Even better!  Excellent finding.  My remaining suggestions stay the same - a 20 year old downhill bike will be lacking in the tech advances of the last two decades.  Unless you already have a good suitable fork with an old-sized steerer tube, its going to be expensive to build up.